node: npm install takes forever and can't finish
I have problem after I tried npm install on docker. Now when I try npm install on my localhost PC even without docker my npm install never finished. In the log file is something about fsevents module error. Before npm install takes few seconds. Right now can't even finish.
Here is the log:
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js1 info using npm@10.8.1
2 info using node@v20.14.0
3 silly config load:file:C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc
4 silly config load:file:C:\Users\username\Documents\Project-NASA\server\.npmrc
5 silly config load:file:C:\Users\username\.npmrc
6 silly config load:file:C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
7 verbose title npm install
8 verbose argv "install" "--prefix" "server"
9 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-28T21_11_23_384Z-
10 verbose logfile C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-28T21_11_23_384Z-debug-0.log
11 silly packumentCache heap:4345298944 maxSize:1086324736 maxEntrySize:543162368
12 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
13 silly logfile error removing log file C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-28T21_11_11_684Z-debug-0.log [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-28T21_11_11_684Z-debug-0.log'] {
13 silly logfile   errno: -4048,
13 silly logfile   code: 'EPERM',
13 silly logfile   syscall: 'lstat',
13 silly logfile   path: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2024-06-28T21_11_11_684Z-debug-0.log'
13 silly logfile }
14 silly logfile done cleaning log files
15 verbose shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json out of date, updated: node_modules
16 silly idealTree buildDeps
17 silly placeDep ROOT project-nasa@1.0.0 REPLACE for: nasa-project-api@1.0.0 want: file:..
18 silly reify mark retired [
18 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Project-NASA\\server\\node_modules\\fsevents'
18 silly reify ]
19 silly reify moves {
19 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Project-NASA\\server\\node_modules\\fsevents': 'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Project-NASA\\server\\node_modules\\.fsevents-T0cSxVM9'
19 silly reify }
20 silly audit bulk request {
{ packages }
20 silly audit }
21 verbose reify failed optional dependency C:\Users\username\Documents\Project-NASA\server\node_modules\fsevents
22 silly reify mark deleted [
22 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Project-NASA\\server\\node_modules\\fsevents'
22 silly reify ]
23 info run project-nasa@1.0.0 install .. npm run install-server && npm run install-client
24 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 359ms
25 silly audit report {
25 silly audit report   ws: [
25 silly audit report     {
25 silly audit report       id: 1097616,
25 silly audit report       url: 'https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3h5v-q93c-6h6q',
25 silly audit report       title: 'ws affected by a DoS when handling a request with many HTTP headers',
25 silly audit report       severity: 'high',
25 silly audit report       vulnerable_versions: '>=7.0.0 <7.5.10',
25 silly audit report       cwe: [Array],
25 silly audit report       cvss: [Object]
25 silly audit report     }
25 silly audit report   ]
25 silly audit report }
26 silly packumentCache corgi:ws cache-miss
27 http fetch GET 200 ws 16ms (cache hit)
28 silly packumentCache corgi:ws set size:189667 disposed:false
29 silly packumentCache corgi:@pm2%2fagent cache-miss
30 silly packumentCache corgi:@pm2%2fjs-api cache-miss
31 http fetch GET 200 @pm2%2fjs-api 8ms (cache hit)
32 silly packumentCache corgi:@pm2%2fjs-api set size:94969 disposed:false
33 http fetch GET 200 @pm2%2fagent 13ms (cache hit)
34 silly packumentCache corgi:@pm2%2fagent set size:68391 disposed:false
35 silly packumentCache corgi:pm2 cache-miss
36 http fetch GET 200 pm2 7ms (cache hit)
37 silly packumentCache corgi:pm2 set size:403394 disposed:false

I have tried changing config registry to http instead https.
Delete Dockerfile.
Change version of npm.
Delete node_modules folders.
Add node.exe to exclusions in Antyvirus Software.
Command that been used:
npm ci
and
npm rebuild
Please any help?

Fix your Internet connection. Highly doubt that you can do anything about it. Do you use a proxy or something similar that tunnels your traffic?

Here it seems that NodeJS is installed on your system, please check in CMD
node -v


Yes. Node is installed and it is the lastest version of node same as npm.
